# Python Pandas- Extracting detailed datas from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Iam trying to extract multiple detailed information using pandas from a dataframe so far without success. I would really appreciate some help as I'am a noob programmer.

I have the following data frame that I'am importing from excel. I have included the attempted code for some of the questions.

The data frame includes 3 manufacturers, 4 product types, distinctive product codes along with their respective launch year.

DATAFRAME:

[image]

QUESTIONS AND DESIRED OUTPUT:

1. Mean Launch Year for the [product type:Metals] of the [manufacturer: Alpha Productions]

I guess question is self explanatory

2. How to print  List of Product codes for the manufacturers Alpha Productions and Supreme Productions

[image]

3. How to print Metals and Electronics product list for Alpha and Lamda Productions

[image]

4. How to display List of Product codes for all manufacturers containing the word 'Construction'

Supreme and Alpha contain the word construction, hence:

[image]

5. Mean Launch Year for Metals products codes of manufacturers containing the word (construction)

This is also self-explanatory. So the output is the mean launch year of output table of question 4.

ATTEMPTED CODES:

QUESTION 1:

```py
x1=df[df.Manufacturer ='Alpha Productions' & df.Product_Code='Metals'].YOB.mean()
print(x1)
```

QUESTION 2:

```py
x2=df[df.Manufacturer =='Alpha Productions' & df.Manufacturer=='Supreme Productions']

print (x2)
```

QUESTION 4:

```
x4=df[df.Manufacturer==str.contains.Construction]

print(x4)
```

Comment: I recommend you break this up into single, narrowly scoped questions to get useful answers.

Comment: What outputs does your attempts give?

Comment: Hi guys, @Artem Vovsia answered my question succesfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you haven't provided a test dataset, I haven't tested these:

Q1:

```py
x1=df[(df.Manufacturer=='Alpha Productions') & (df.Product_Code=='Metals')].Launch_Year.mean()
print(x1)
```

Q2:

```py
x2=df[(df.Manufacturer =='Alpha Productions') | (df.Manufacturer=='Supreme Productions')]

print (x2)
```

Q3:

```py
mask_manufacturer = (df.Manufacturer=='Alpha') | (df.Manufacturer=='Lamda Productions')
mask_type = (df.Product_Type=='Metals') | (df.Product_Type=='Electronics')

print(df[mask_manufacturer & mask_type]
```

Q4:

```
x4=df[df.Manufacturer.str.contains("Construction")].Product_Code

print(x4)
```

Q5:

```
x5=df[df.Manufacturer.str.contains("Construction") & df.Product_Type == "Metals"].Launch_Year.mean()

print(x5)
```

Comment: thanks mate. appreciated.